# Besides the output to the terminal, does sys.stdout.flush also flush the file writing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

If not, is there any function to flush the butter of fileIO?

Comment: It's probably *possible*, but it's a truly horrible idea in most cases.

Comment: @ceejayoz so you have some other good idea?

Comment: Yes. Upgrade your server to have more storage or offload files to something like Amazon S3. Having it depend on your local PC, home internet, and dynamic IP is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: hoho, that's really an expensive solution... I have to ask people if they are willing to spend the money..............

Comment: Both storage and S3 are relatively cheap. Much cheaper for most people than the reputation and maintenance damage of cobbling together a horrible solution out of stuff you have lying around at home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly this is possible from a technical point of view:

You need some sort of volume server for this. Typically used are either `nfs` or `samba` for such task, though many other options exist. You can use these to "export" the volume for usage by other systems. This also means, that you need to attach that "portable disk" (probably some sort of USB volume) to some local system where such software is installed and executed on.

However there is one issue here: the remote, importing (so mounting) system must be able to reach the exporting system on the network. So the exporting system must be visible on the network or even internet. This certainly is possible, but might require a little more effort if you do not have a static, routeable ip address for the exporting system. In such cases this is not really a good idea, since the reliability of the whole setup is questionable.

Comment: I am not sure if you need root or sudo to mount something ?

Comment: @Marged That depends, actually. There is some thing called "user space mounting". And aso the system might be configured such that certain types of mounts can be granted to non-privilidged users.

Comment: Thanks @arkascha. I'm googling and reading stuff about nfs. I don't have a public IP on my local PC.

Comment: As said: in that case this probably is _not_ a good idea. If you still want to give it a try: also read about "dynamic dns".

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @arkascha .It might be a bad idea. Anyhow I need to find a solution for my problem. Everyday I need to manully download and remove processed data from the server to make some space for uploading new source data to the server. I'm tired of that and I'm not sure someday I make some mistakes......

Comment: Well, get some bigger system/account, since apparently the current one is to small. Webspace doesn't cost anything anymore...